# Prevent SQL injection when building query

Tags: sql-server, language-agnostic

I know usually how to prevent it using preparedStatements, but now I have such a method for bulding queries. For example in Java:

```java
private String buildQuery(String where) {
    String query = "SELECT id, name FROM someTable";
    if(where.length() > 0) {
        query = query + " WHERE " + where;
    }
    return query;
}
```

'where' string is like this 'variable = value'. How can i prevent it here? I thought of passing variable and value separately, creating prepared statement using them and then returning that prepared statement as string somehow, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Such "methods for building queries" are usually a very poor approach in themselves, not only for this reason.

Comment: I feel that you should be passing not `String` as parameter type but `String[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to any one DB API.

TL;DR: Don't pass "SQL fragments" around.

Rather than passing complete clauses fro a select statement, or (sub-)expressions to add into a select clause, pass the components keeping the user data separate from the identifiers.

In this case do not pass `name = value`, pass them separately. Then validate `name` is a valid column for the table, and generate a parameter for the `value` part.

Thus, pseudo-code (my Java is rusty):

```
function BuildCommand(string column, object value) {
  if !IsValidColumn("theTable", column)) throw InvalidOperation(...)

  string sql = "Select column from theTable where " + column + " = @p0";

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@p0", value);

  return cmd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to pass your values and build a preparedStatement. Check the code below it should be something similar to that logic

```
public static PreparedStatement buildQuery(String where,Map<Integer, String> cond)
        throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement stat = null;

    String query = "SELECT id, name FROM someTable " + where;

    try {
        stat = con.prepareStatement(query);

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : cond.entrySet()) {
            stat.setString(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        // Handle ex
    } finally {

    }
    return  stat;
}


public static void main(String[] a) throws SQLException {
    Map<Integer,String> cond =new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    cond.put(1,"val22");
    cond.put(2,"val2");


    buildQuery("col1 = ? and col2= ?", cond);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that if you have an array of where clauses in the parameter and rewrite the function as :

```
private String buildQuery(String[] where) {
    String query = "SELECT id, name FROM someTable";
    query = query + " WHERE "
    for(int i = 0; i < where.length; i++) {
        if(i > 0){
            query = query + " AND "
        }
        query = query + w + " = ?";
    }
    return query;
}
```